# Unique values query without aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an index of unique products where each document represents a single product, with the following fields: product_id, group_id, group_score, and product_score.
Consider the following index:

```
{
    "product_id": "100-001",
    "group_id": "100",
    "group_score": 100,
    "product_score": 60,
},
{
    "product_id": "100-002",
    "group_id": "100",
    "group_score": 100,
    "product_score": 40,
},
{
    "product_id": "100-001",
    "group_id": "100",
    "group_score": 100,
    "product_score": 50,
},
{
    "product_id": "200-001",
    "group_id": "200",
    "group_score": 73,
    "product_score": 20,
},
{
    "product_id": "200-002",
    "group_id": "200",
    "group_score": 73,
    "product_score": 53,
}
```

Every group contains ~1-200 products. 
We are trying to a query that matches the following conditions:
1. Products should be sorted by their group_score (desc).
2. No more than one product per group_id.
3. Get the product with the highest product_score within the group.

For example, applying the query on the above should return:

```
{
   "product_id": "100-001"
},
{
   "product_id": "200-002"
}
```

We ended up with the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_group_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "group_id",
        "order":{
            "max_group_score":"desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_scores_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "product_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        },
        "max_group_score":{
            "max":{
                "field":"group_score"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the query is really slow because of the aggregations and the search performance is important.

We would love to hear your opinion about a better/efficient solution.

**Changing the index structure is tolerable**.

Comment: How many group you have? If you only have 100-200 products by groups, maybe he could be better do nested all products in the groupid documents (buts its depend of your context and your others search or update querry). If you donc need real time results, you could cache your agg results.

Comment: We are thinking about doing it with nested or parent/child. 1. Can you explain how it will improve? 2. How could I make sure that the agg results are cached?

Comment: 1: If you already got all products in a single document (groupid) you wont have to make the first aggregation, because your products already will be group by groupid.

Comment: 2: Take a look to, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/caching-heavy-aggregations.html , https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html in order to cache aggregation. You could have a bot querring aggregation each X minutes, get your results should be pretty fast then.

Comment: I think cache is enabled by default, because I see improvement after the first query and still its still not satisfied and need to be faster.

Comment: By default if size = 0 yes cache is enabled for aggregation.

Comment: I suspect the sort size 1 to be the problem, could you make a try on a query with max : product_score as subaggregation and tell us if it is pretty fast (replace the sort by a max in order to know if the sort is the problem, i know this isnot the result you want) ?

Comment: will check and update! thanks